# how do update open files ulimit for non user

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, redhat

The root user runs the following

```
ulimit -a | grep open
```

and gets a result of

```
open files (-n) 65536
```

A user runs the same command and gets a result of

```
open files (-n) 65000
```

How can you set the ulimit of the user to 8162?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can just run `ulimit -n` to reduce the limit:

```
$ ulimit -n 8192
$ ulimit -n
8192
```

However, the user can override this limit.  If you want to establish a hard limit for this user, you need to edit the file `/etc/security/limits.conf`.